# Statistical Inference, Differential Geometry and Entropy

Tags: differential-geometry, statistical-inference, entropy

Context: Statistical Inference and Differential Geometry

Let's consider a generic $ p(x;\theta) $ distribution with $ \theta $ Parameters Vector, it is obvious that 
$$ \int p(x; \theta) dx = 1 $$

and by definition it should be exactly 1 for any value of $ \theta $ hence 
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_{i}} \int p(x; \theta) = 0 $$

Then now let's consider the negative entropy of the distribution (the expected value of the log distribution)
$$ S = E_{\theta}\left [ \ln(p(x; \theta)) \right ] = \int \ln(p(x;\theta)) p(x; \theta) dx $$

applying the derivative internally we should ge 
$$ E_{\theta}\left [ \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_{i}} \ln(p(x; \theta)) \right ] = \int \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_{i}} \ln(p(x; \theta)) p(x; \theta) dx = \int \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_{i}} p(x; \theta)  \quad \forall i $$

Now if it would be possible to move freely the derivative in and out the of the integral it will be possible to see that 
$$ E_{\theta}\left [ \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_{i}} \ln(p(x; \theta)) \right ] = \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_{i}} E_{\theta} \left [ \ln(p(x; \theta)) \right ] $$

hence the (negative) entropy seems constant with respect to the parameters but this does not seem correct to me: let's consider for example the gaussian distribution and it is easy to observe that its entropy depends on the variance.

Maybe the problem is that the above mentioned parametrization is different or does it depend on the possibility to move the derivative freely in and out the integral of the expected value ?

Comment: excuse my ignorance, how does this relate to differential geometry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is here:

$$ E_{\theta}\left [ \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_{i}} \ln(p(x; \theta)) \right ] = \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_{i}} E_{\theta} \left [ \ln(p(x; \theta)) \right ] $$

This is incorrect as the density depends on $\theta$: when writing the derivative there is one additional term
$$
E_\theta\left[\ln p(x;\theta) \frac{\partial p(x;\theta)}{\partial\theta}\right]
$$

Comment: It seems correct to me ... 
$$ \int \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_{i}} \ln(p(x; \theta)) p(x; \theta) dx = \int \frac{1}{p(x;\theta)}p(x; \theta) \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_{i}}p(x; \theta) = \int \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_{i}} p(x; \theta)  \quad \forall i  $$

Comment: you have to add the derivation of the term $p(x,\theta) dx$ with respect to $\theta$! $ \frac d{d\theta}\int \log P Pdx = \int (\frac{ dP/{d\theta}} P \times P + \log P \frac d{d\theta} P) dx$

Comment: Sorry my notation was not clear: the function passed to the expected value operator is the partial derivative of the log distribution hence the proper integral is 
$$ E_{\theta}\left [ \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_{i}} \ln(p(x; \theta)) \right ] = \int \left ( \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_{i}} \ln(p(x; \theta)) \right ) p(x; \theta) dx $$

the remaining part of the computation should then be as I've written it

Comment: I get that the second equality is correct. But you can't apply the derivative 'internally' and hope that $ E_{\theta}\left [ \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_{i}} \ln(p(x; \theta)) \right ] = \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_{i}} E_{\theta} \left [ \ln(p(x; \theta)) \right ] $ because of the weight depending on $\theta$ as well.

Comment: also, see the edit of the answer.

Comment: @mookid is right: moving the partial derivative inside the integral produces 2 contributions as one derives the product $\ln(p(x;\theta)))p(x;\theta)$

Comment: @Avitus 
The issue regarding the second term is correct but to me it is not the term that mookid wrote because he used the exptected value while it should have been used just the integral as Nicola Bernini wrote. 
Is this correct ?

Comment: @NikolaTesla this is funny that you are pedantic about the posts of people trying to help you when you ask to explain your mistake in a question.

Comment: mookid correctly identified the source of the problem, @Nikola Testla, and this answers to your question. There exists a typo in the answer he can quickly correct. In general I would try to be supportive with people who answer to questions. The presence of a (not critical, as in this case) error can be simply highlighted, maybe with a question like "are you sure about...? I arrive at another result" et similia.

Comment: @mookid 
Sorry I did not want to be pedantic but just to be sure about the answer ...

Comment: @NikolaTesla: no problem. The most important part is that you have a satisfactory answer at the end of the day.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can see the problem is that $ \partial_{\theta_{i}} E_{\theta}[\ln(p)] \neq E_{\theta}[\partial_{\theta_{i}} \ln(p)] $

You wrote $ E_{\theta}[\partial_{\theta_{i}} \ln(p)] $ correctly while the other term is 
$$ \partial_{\theta_{i}} E_{\theta}[\ln(p)] = \int \left ( \partial_{\theta_{i}} \ln(p(x;\theta)) \right ) p(x;\theta) dx + \int \ln(p(x;\theta)) \left ( \partial_{\theta_{i}} p(x; \theta) \right ) dx $$

hence 
$$ \partial_{\theta_{i}} E_{\theta}[\ln(p)] = \int \partial_{\theta_{i}}p(x;\theta)dx + \int \ln(p(x;\theta)) \left ( \partial_{\theta_{i}} p(x; \theta) \right ) dx $$

Regarding the first term, the integration is over $ x $ and the partial derivation is overo $ \theta_{i} $ hence it should be possible to write 
$$ \int \partial_{\theta_{i}}p(x;\theta)dx = \partial_{\theta_{i}} \int p(x; \theta) dx = 0 $$

as you have already demonstrated above so it follows that 
$$ \partial_{\theta_{i}} E_{\theta}[\ln(p)] = \int \ln(p(x;\theta)) \left ( \partial_{\theta_{i}} p(x; \theta) \right ) dx $$

In case $ p(x; \theta) \sim \exp \left ( f(x; \theta) \right ) $ the distribution is part of the exponential family the above term becomes
$$ \partial_{\theta_{i}} E_{\theta}[\ln(p)] = \int f(x; \theta) \partial_{\theta_{i}}f(x; \theta) p(x; \theta) dx $$

then 
$$ \partial_{\theta_{i}} E_{\theta}[\ln(p)] = E_{\theta}[ f(x; \theta) ( \partial_{\theta_{i}}f(x; \theta)) ] $$

hence the variation of entropy of the distribution is not independent of the parameters variation

Answer (score 0):

I believe it more clear to restate Nicola Bernini's conclusion by writing:

Hence, the variation of ensemble-average entropy of the distribution is dependent on the parameters of the distribution.

I believe this to be so for two reasons: first, the above distinguishes between the entropy $\ln(p)$ and the ensemble-average entropy $E_\theta[\ln(p)]$; and second it excludes an unnecessary double negative (i.e., 'not independent').